# Progress on Epic in TFS 2017 on-premises

Tags: tfs, burndowncharts

We have been using TFS for a number of years and I still struggle to get a handle on the progress (e.g. burndown) of an Epic.

The Epic spans multiple team backlogs.

We use the Scrum template and are on TFS 2017 on-premises version.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install this [Feature timeline and Epic Roadmap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension) to your TFS.

**FeaturTimelinene**

[image]

**UserStories chart**

[image]

**Extending your feature sprint**

[image]